# JSON-LD schema.org dynamically built with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, schema.org, json-ld

I would like to add structured data using JSON-LD. I try to dynamically get content using jQuery and making JSON format and appending inside the head element. I can get text values from a specific div for Question and for Answer, but not for all, as i have more div that have the ID starting with heading (for Question) and collapse (for answer).
Below what i want to achieve:

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "FAQPage",
  "mainEntity": [{
    "@type": "Question",
    "name": "q1",
    "acceptedAnswer": {
      "@type": "Answer",
      "text": "a1"
    }
  },{
    "@type": "Question",
    "name": "q2",
    "acceptedAnswer": {
      "@type": "Answer",
      "text": "a2"
    }
  }]
}
```

I use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var q_name = $('[id^=heading]').text();
var q_answer = $('[id^=collapse]').text();


       var el = document.createElement('script');
       el.type = 'application/ld+json';
       el.text = JSON.stringify({
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "FAQPage",
  "mainEntity": {
    "@type": "Question",
    "name": q_name,
    "acceptedAnswer": {
      "@type": "Answer",
      "text": q_answer
    }
  }
});

document.querySelector('head').appendChild(el);
});
```

Comment: Header info is usually picked up by tooling which will not run javascript, so if you're not server-side rendering this content, you might have problems. See https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/generate-structured-data-with-javascript and https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/javascript-seo-basics

Comment: try this: http://trevorfox.com/schema-test.html

Comment: Schema from my example is working. I have tested in google. My problem is that i cant generate for each div text. I can just for one. I need to create this for each  div ID  `{
    "@type": "Question",
    "name": "q2",
    "acceptedAnswer": {
      "@type": "Answer",
      "text": "a2"
    }`